# How do I undo check out in TFS for former employees

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs, active-directory

On our TFS source control server, a lot of source files are checked out by people, which are not employed any more.

Is there a central way where I can undo check out on all files in TFS?

I'm not even sure that they exists in Active Directory anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best thing to do is to delete their workspace using with the command line tool (tf.exe) or the [TFS Sidekicks from Attrice](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/).

See the following blog post I did on the topic when it happened to me, and I detailed the command line version:

http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/unlocking_files.html

Answer (score 7):

There are command line tools that can do this.

However, I find the [sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) tool much easier to use (it is free and stable.)

You can undo check out easily.  There's much more in there that makes it well worth the installation.