# Files in check-out for an employee who left the company

Tags: version-control, tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I undo check out in TFS for former employees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258202/how-do-i-undo-check-out-in-tfs-for-former-employees)

How do a clear/remove the check-out status of some files for an employee that left the company in TFS2010?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: **[How do I rollback a TFS check-in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607/how-do-i-rollback-a-tfs-check-in)** and **[How do I undo check out in TFS for former employees](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258202/how-do-i-undo-check-out-in-tfs-for-former-employees)**

Answer (score 1):

Your TFS admin should be able to release the locks...

Alternatively, have your network admin temporarily reinstate his account with a new password, and handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Team Foundation Sidekick](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tfsidekicks/archive/2010/01/03/team-foundation-sidekicks-for-2010-available.aspx) it has GUI for Unlock files by others, but you must have permission to do that.

Answer (score 0):

At first, right click on the TeamProject root in Source Control Explorer, select "Properties", then "Security" & check if you have the rights to 
"Unlock other users' changes" and 
"Undo other users' changes".
Once you 're done, Right-Click again and select "Find in Source Control" > "Status" and choose to "Display files checked out to:" = the employee who left
 All you now need to do is select all checkouts in the list and choose "Undo".

**EDIT**:
The `Find in Source Control` is to be found in the Source Control Explorer, if you right click and simply select it:
[image]
It's possible that its' existence is related with [Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) - so if you don't see this menu consider installing them.

Comment: I can't find the `Find in Source Control` command, where is it?

Comment: @devdept: In the TFS Power Tools.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963